# Would it cause retain cycle that add a subview on a view passed by parameter of a function?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

For example:

```
// CustomViewClass

- (void)showOnView: (UIView*)view {
    [view addSubview: self.customView];
}
```

Then invoke this method at another class, like a view controller's `viewDidLoad`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.customViewClass showOnView: self.view];
}
```

I pass a view controller's view to `CustomViewClass` as the above.

**My question is:**   Would it cause some kind of retain cycle?

Are these views passed through parameter referenced weakly?
Or it's fine to that.

It would be highly appreciated if anyone explain it in both **Swift** and **Objective-C**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is Retain Cycle? - It's the condition when 2 objects keep a reference to each other and are retained, it creates a retain cycle since both objects try to retain each other, making it impossible to release.

In this case, `self.customViewClass` keep a reference to `self.view` but `self.view` doesn't keep any reference to `self.customViewClass`. Which keeps reference to `self.customViewClass` is `self`, not `self.view`.

So of course, ***it won't causes retain cycle***

**Don't believe in me ?**  - Check it yourself by trying to log something inside `dealloc` method.

After you dismiss `CustomViewController`, if the code inside `dealloc` is called and log something, it means no retain cycle here. If not, it causes retain cycle.

For example

```
- (void)dealloc {
  NSLog(@"BOOM RIGHT ANSWER!!!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Memory leaks happens when two class having objects pointing to each other .For e.g.

```
 class A{
   var object_b = B()
 }

 class B{
   var object_a = A()
 }
```

Now consider your case :
// CustomViewClass

```
- (void)showOnView: (UIView*)view {
    [view addSubview: self.customView];
}
```

Your" view" object is local variable .CustomViewClass doest not reference to superview "view".

Now when customview is added to superview:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.customViewClass showOnView: self.view];
}
```

When showOnView function of CustomViewClass called the superview simply adds subview CustomViewClass view.

For finding memory leaks always add deinit function in views and viewController class so that you can sure about class is deallocated or not.

```
deinit {
    print("deinit called " + "Class name")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't lead to a retain cycle. It is a one way reference of object where parent view has it's reference in a secondary(custom) view. However there is no reference of that secondary view in the parent view. So unless that situation arises, you are quite safe as far as retain cycle is concerned and there is no need of a weak reference of the parent view.